# How do I rewrite dockerfile (and run commands) as docker-compose.yaml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Tell me the way to translate docker command into docker-compose command.

Using docker command, I can see my app working on `http://localhost:9000`.
But in another case, it doesn't.
Though it may be cause of specifying ports mapping, I have no idea.
What's the reason for?

Followings are files and commands I've tried.

dockerfile

```
FROM node:8.11.3-alpine

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk update \
    && npm install -g npm @vue/cli \
    && npm install

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  service:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9000:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
```

docker command: ok

```sh
sudo docker run -it -v $(pwd):/app -p 9000:8080 dockerimage
```

docker-compose command: problem

```sh
sudo dock-compose run service
```

Comment: Try `docker-compose up`.

Comment: Do you have any log output from the docker-compose command? Also two errors from your examples: The command for docker compose is `docker-compose` and not `dock-compose`. Also you have an unnecessary execution of `npm install` in your `Dockerfile`.